# 5 men went fishing and caught not more than 12 fish. In how many ways it can be done if each man may have caught any number of fish?

Tags: combinatorics

> 5 men went fishing and caught not more than 12 fish. In how many ways it can be done if each man may have caught any number of fish?

I was thinking of partition again
N=12 and r=5
so, 12+5-1C5-1=16C4

But the answer is 17C5 assuming r as 6
Please explain

Comment: $\leq12$ is not the same as $=12$ of course.

Answer (score 1):

You're wrong because it doesn't say that that the number of fish is *exactly* $12$, yet that it is *no more than* $12$. So how do we get over that?

Suppose the men caught $n$ fish, with $n \le 12$. Then you can imagine that the remaining $12 - n$ fish were caught by a sixth man: together, the six men caught exactly $12$ fish, so now we are left with computing the partitions of $12$ objects in $6$ boxes. These are $$\binom{12 + 6 - 1}{6 - 1} = \binom{17}{5}$$ which is exactly what we wanted.

Formally, what we did was showing that a partition exists between the set of all quintuples $(a, \: b, \: c, \: d, \: e)$ of nonnegative integers such that $a + b + c + d + e \le 12$ and the set of all the sextuples $(a, \: b, \: c, \: d, \: e, \: f)$ of nonnegative integers such that $a + b + c + d + e + f = 12$, then count the elements of the second set.

Comment: why we are assuming sixth man when only 5 men went for fishing? @cip999

Comment: The sixth man is not part of the five that went fishing, it's additional. If you're uncomfortable with the fishing thing, focus on the formalisation below (which is exactly the same thing, said in a more "mathematical" way) and try to understand that.

Answer (score 0):

To be found is the number of sums $a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4+a_5+b=12$ where the $a_i$ and $b$ are nonnegative integers.

With stars and bars we find $\binom{12+5}{5}$ possibilities.

Here $b$ stands for $12$ minus the number of fishes that have been caught.

It is allowed to be positive, and this is what you did not take into account.

Comment: why we are assuming b when only 5 men went to fishing? @drhab

Comment: The number of ways that not more than 12 fishes can be caught by 5 men equals the number of ways that exactly 12 fishes can be caught by 6 men. If e.g. the 5 men catch 7 then think of $b$ as the one catching 5